# how to like page in facebook by api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I had used the action of like to like a page in the facebook

> $response = $facebook->api( "/{page-id}/likes" ,
>       "POST" , $data );

from 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/likes

I add the token in the $data array as I used it with other functions and it work.
But with the likes it's not

The response were:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) App does not have permission to make this call", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only like an Open Graph object with the API, but not a Facebook Page. Would be a big problem if that would be allowed, you could just Auto-Like any Page you want after the user authorized your App.